# Node.js echo's multiple blank lines after a command

Tags: node.js, bash, git, terminal

So whenever I run any command it randomly places empty lines, sometimes at the end of the output, sometimes it just puts empty lines instead of output. How can I fix this?

[image: screenshot]

I've looked in the Internet, and found these kind of issues but never found an answer.

UPD: as tripleee said it's node.js that does these kind of things, no background processes or anything else just plain command, and it does the same with bare terminal window outside the IDE

Comment: Your screenshot looks like it's `node.js` doing the empty lines; what indication do you have that it's Bash? It doesn't do this out of the box; do you have a background process running which emits empty lines occasionally? Voting to close as requiring debugging details.

Comment: Also, you seem to be running inside some IDE or editor (VS Code?) Do you see the same symptom in a bare terminal window?

Comment: Try to turn off whatever is providing that `(master)` prompt.

Comment: triplee, it gives same things in vs code and in a bare terminal window

Comment: Does it happen with node only? Does it happen if you redirect a file? Does it happen if you `cat` that file's content? Does it always happen? Is `node` the bare binary or an alias which wraps the command (e.g. in `winpty`?)